# C++ map with custom comparator is not inserting all elements

Tags: c++, comparator

I have the following code:

```
enum Type {
  OUTPUT = 1,
  INPUT = 2,
  INOUT = 3
};

std::vector<int> data = {INPUT, INOUT, OUTPUT, INPUT, OUTPUT, INPUT}
```

My goal is to store information into a `std::map<int, char>` where the key is index in `data` and value is some character. I want it to be ordered in such a way that those indexes for which in `data` they have value `INPUT` would be in the beginning.

I tried to write a custom comparator:

```
struct Comparator {
  bool operator()(int lhs, int rhs) {
    if (data[lhs] == INPUT && data[rhs] != INPUT) {
      return true;
    } else if (data[lhs] != INPUT && data[rhs] == INPUT) {
      return false;
    }

    return data[lhs] < data[rhs]
  }
};
```

But for the following code

```
int main()
{
  std::map<int, char, Comparator> m;

  for (unsigned i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
    m.insert( {i, 'a' + i} );
  }
}
```

my map's values are

```
0 -> 'a'
2 -> 'c'
1 -> 'b'
```

I expected to have 6 elements in it, first three being `0 -> 'a', 3 -> 'd', 5 -> 'f'`

Comment: Do you want `std::multimap` ?

Comment: Keys must be unique, and your compare operator must be able to come up with an ordering (which it cannot do now). So probably you need a key that is a combination of input/ouput and an address

Comment: what output did you expect?

Comment: I expected to have 6 elements in it, first three being `0 -> 'a', 3 -> 'd', 5 -> 'f'`

Comment: When you do an [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert), you might want to consider checking it's return value to see if the insert failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You order based on values stored in `data` and you only have 3 values stored in there, so you can only get 3 values in the map at most.

Your ordering should be based on `lhs` and `rhs` rather than `data[lhs]`/`data[rhs]`:

```
struct Comparator {
  bool operator()(int lhs, int rhs) const /* note the const here */ {
    if (data[lhs] == INPUT && data[rhs] != INPUT) {
      return true;
    } else if (data[lhs] != INPUT && data[rhs] == INPUT) {
      return false;
    }

    // either both are INPUT or both are not,
    // so compare lhs and rhs, not the values in data
    return lhs < rhs; 
  }
};
```

[See it online](https://godbolt.org/z/PjPEWqMeK)

Comment: Possibly: `return std::pair(data[lhs] != INPUT, lhs) < std::pair(data[rhs] != INPUT, rhs);` or `const auto proj = [&](int i){return std::pair(data[i] != INPUT, i); }; return proj(lhs) < proj(rhs);`